# Net::Async::WebSocket::Server in a separate main loop

Tags: perl, websocket, server

I am trying to achieve a fairly simple thing: I want to run a websocket server which is controlled by a main loop instead of the Async::Loop, like this:

```
my $sslSocket = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
    Listen             => 5,
    LocalPort          => XXX,
    Proto              => 'tcp',
    SSL_startHandshake => 0,
    SSL_cert_file      => 'XXX',
    SSL_key_file       => 'XXX',
  ) or die "failed to listen: $!";

  my $server = Net::Async::WebSocket::Server->new(
    on_client => sub {
      my ( undef, $client ) = @_;

      $client->configure(
        on_text_frame => sub {
          my ( $self, $frame ) = @_;

          $self->send_text_frame( $frame );
        },
      );
    },
    on_handshake => sub {
      my ( $self, $client, $hs, $continue ) = @_;

      $continue->( 1 );
    }
  );

  my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new;
  $loop->add( $server );

  $server->listen(
    handle => $sslSocket
  )->get;
```

In the main loop I am calling "$loop->loop_once" whenever the listening socket "$sslSocket" has data available, like this:

```
while(1){
  // something before
  if (//data to read) {
    $loop->loop_once;
  }
  // something after
}
```

Unfortunately the websocket connection is never established. None of the callbacks is called. I think I am getting the purpose of "loop_once" wrong but I don't know what the exact issue is.

I already tried to use $loop->run", then the connection can be established correctly. But this is not what I require.

Thanks for help!

Bye

Expectation is that the websocket server is processing outstanding requests when "loop_once" is called.

Comment: Remove `if (//data to read)`. But really, you're doing things inside out. `// something before` and `// something after` should be done in response to some even (e.g. being idle)

Comment: Well, the thing is that the main loop is outside of my control, the only thing I can get there is a hook which calls my logic whenever a socket has data. Which means the "while" loop already exists and the only thing I can control is what happens inside the "if"-block. That is why I am asking for a way to trigger the websocket server processing when the socket has data.

Comment: Wrong. You need to process events as long as there are events to process. Like I said, you need to remove `if (//data to read)`, which is  to say you want to use `$loop->loop_once;` unconditionally.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The concept like I planned it, does not work, as information gets lost. I tried to call the "loop_once" unconditionally, but this causes the main loop to hang too often. The only solution for now is to use threads. I wanted to avoid it (because of the copying of current application state), but as I only create 1 thread it shouldn't be much of a problem. Thanks!

Comment: oh, I didn't realize loop_once hangs when there's nothing to do.